# Nested destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Say I have an object with a shape like so:

```
{
  rows: [
    {some: fields,
     go: here}]
}
```

, and say that, in a particular case, I knew that the length of rows is 1. How could I extract {some: fields, go: here} through destructuring?

I have attempted: `{rows: [stuff]}`, and `{rows: stuff}` but in both cases `console.log(stuff)` prints `[{some: fields, go: here}]` How can I do this through destructuring?

Answer (score 0):

`{rows: [stuff]}` works fine:

```js
const obj = {
  rows: [
    {some: 'fields',
     go: 'here'}]
};

const { rows: [stuff] } = obj;
console.log(stuff);
```

Comment: Why are you getting all of these downvotes? I think your answer works just fine according to my reading. It's super annoying when people downvote answers just because they downvote the question because they think it's a duplicate.